# How to make an async call to blocking CFFI functions

Tags: python, c, asynchronous, blocking, python-cffi

I have a set of blocking C-based functions. I am trying to find a way to make async calls to those blocking functions from python. Is there a way to do this from a python interface?

for example

```
 async def my_func():
      
      ffi.blocking_c_function()   # this will be blocking for seconds or even mins
```

This blocking function may take seconds or minutes before it finishes.
How would be the behaviour of the above async python func?

I would appreciate any advice

Comment: Are you looking to make that an ``async`` function (e.g. for ``asyncio``, ``trio``, etc.) or an "asynchronous" function (e.g. ``threading``, ``gevent``, ...)?

Comment: I am looking to make that an async function (e.g asyncio) if possible, this would be easier than spawning another thread

Comment: The straightforward way is to use ``asyncio`` to spawn and track a python thread. Is that sufficient for you? If the `blocking_c_function` does not need the gil, one could probably use a native thread that merely uses an ``asyncio`` flag to communicate success.